# TabActivity and child tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a tabActivity class.

```
class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec tabOne= tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab One");
tabOne.setIndicator("Tab One", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1));
Intent tabOneIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
tabOne.setContent(tabOneIntent);

TabSpec tabTwo= tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
tabTwo.setIndicator("Tab Two", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2));
Intent tabTwoIntent = new Intent(this, TabTwo.class);
tabTwo.setContent(videosIntent);

tabHost.addTab(tabOne);
tabHost.addTab(tabTwo);
}
```

And one of the tabs is

```
class TabTwo extends Acitity implements OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View view) {
       //open a new activity within the tab  
    }
}
```

And the dummy activity is

```
class DummyActivity extends Activity {
}
```

When I click tab two, TabTwo class is invoked. When I click a button from within the class, I want to open a DummyActivity within the tab. The code being used now is

```
context.startActivity(intentObject);
```

This will open the new activity in absolutely new window. How can I open the DummyActivity from within the tab?

Thanks in advance!

@all Thanks for the responses. I solved the issue using ActivityGroup and child activties.

Comment: I opened activity normally from the listener like context.startActivity(new Intent((TabTwo)context, DummyActivity.class));

Comment: You could set TabTwo to `ViewSwitcher` Layout and solve it this way.
Or make `tabTwo` static and set its content new. Maybe it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It does not looks like usual android app experience. Be very careful with doing such things.
2. Since 3.0 it's better to use [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). If you want to support earlier devices - use compatibility library.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't use `context.startActivity(intentObject);`

Look here:

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
    videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
    videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(photospec);
    tabHost.addTab(videospec);
```

From http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

You have to use a `TabHost`, a `TabSpec` and a `Intent` for a Tab. And then `TabHost.addTab(TabSpec)`

Comment: Question edited! I am using TabHost. The motive is to open a child activity from with TabTwo.class

Answer (score 0):

use like this first Tab

```
 public class TabsActivity extends TabActivity {

      TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabone");
    spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "tabone", R.drawable.tab_home));
    Intent inte = new Intent(TabsActivity.this, PhotosActivity.class);
    inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec1.setContent(inte);


    TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabtwo");
    spec2.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "tabtwo", R.drawable.tab_account));
    Intent _int = new Intent(TabsActivity.this, TabTwoActivity.class);
    _int.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec2.setContent(_int);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

an second Tab

```
        public class TabTwoActivity extends TabActivity {

       TabSpec spec1 = tabHostacc.newTabSpec("tabone");
    spec1.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHostacc.getContext(), "tabone", R.drawable.tab_home));
    Intent inte = new Intent(TabTwoActivity .this,  yourfirstActivity.class);
    inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec1.setContent(inte);      

    TabSpec spec2 = tabHostacc.newTabSpec("tabtwo");
    spec2.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHostacc.getContext(), "tabtwo", R.drawable.tab_account));
    Intent _int = new Intent(TabTwoActivity .this, yoursecondActivity.class);
    _int.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    spec2.setContent(_int);      

    tabHostacc.addTab(spec1);
    tabHostacc.addTab(spec2);
```

demoActivityes

```
    class yourfirstActivity extends Activity {
     }

     class yoursecondActivityextends Activity {
     }
```